# Android - How to stop the runnable and handler method

Tags: java, android

In my application i will be keep on updating some info in some time interval.so i have done like this

```
     handler = new Handler();
     and then some Task
     handler.postDelayed(runLocation, 1000);                                                

    public Runnable runLocation = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
    MainActivity.this.handler.postDelayed(MainActivity.this.runLocation, 100);

};
```

My problem is i want to stop this runnable at some point of time.how to do this ?
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [removeCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)). Just call

```
  handler.removeCallbacks(runLocation);
```

it will remove any pending items in the message's queue.

Comment: Where to call this method

Comment: *My problem is i want to stop this runnable at some point of time*. At that same point ?

Comment: after getting all info that i need in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`removeCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable))

```
@Override
public void run() {
  if(isStopHandler){
   MainActivity.this.handler.removeCallbacks(this);
   return;
  }
  // do your runnable work
  // set isStopHandler = true when needed so next time this method is executed, it will get inside if cond.
};
```